# This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have to get data from 2 tables with limited tables I'm using this query and facing an error `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`

```
   SELECT S.* FROM softwares S
   WHERE S.SoftId IN (
     SELECT V.* FROM versions as V
     WHERE V.SoftId = S.SoftId
     ORDER BY DateAdded DESC LIMIT 1
   ) LIMIT 5
```

I've to select All columns from Versions and Softwares Where Softwars.SoftId = Versions.SoftId, And Select Latest Version From Table Versions.
Thanks

Comment: you could use a join, which is almost always more efficient than a sub-query.

Comment: I also tried this one
`SELECT S.* FROM softwares S INNER JOIN (select V.* FROM versions V LIMIT 1) AS Version ON Version.SoftId = S.SoftId LIMIT 5`

Comment: But this returns just one row, Can you please write query for me ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the last matching record out the versions table which is matching the software table by soffid record and limit the complete resultset with a max off 5 records?

Comment: I have 10 softwares with each contains 5 versions, I have to select 5 software rows, each should contain latest version

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "**Help others reproduce the problem**" is important..

Comment: Sorry I'm non english guy, so written this with my full effort, can you please Improve my question and can help ?

Comment: @IdontDownVote Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*,v.*
FROM softwares s LEFT JOIN versions v ON s.SoftId = v.SoftId
WHERE DateAdded IS NULL
    OR DateAdded = (
        SELECT MAX(DateAdded)
        FROM versions v2
        WHERE v2.SoftId = s.SoftId
    )
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bNYJL5eobFYP3TRukA1Wi7/0

Comment: Check out here, It is returning 7 rows
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8eSZQDi7yUyHsXEf33vqrn/2
It should return 3 Software rows With Each Having One Version Row Where SoftID is Same (Version Row Order By DateAdded)
PS. I have to use these result as Software list by `foreach` Function Of PHP

Comment: switch to use DateAdded: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bNYJL5eobFYP3TRukA1Wi7/0 `Version` also works, but double check the internal sort is what you expect.